# How to identify the tables in use by SQL?

Tags: postgresql

I was handed over a tool but not a concrete documentation for it.
Currently, one of my challenges is to identify which tables in their DB (PostgreSQL 10) are actually used and which are left over from the mess during making this tool (There are 600 tables in the DB).
One thing I could think of is to look for the last timestamp/date that each table has been modified/accessed/queried! (The tool is used daily, right now)
Does PostgreSQL provide anything you know that helps me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One thing I could think of is to look for the last timestamp/date that each table has been modified/accessed/queried!

Postgres doesn't store that information.

What you can do, is save a snapshot of [pg_statio_all_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STATIO-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) then after a while save another snapshot and compare the values. If there was no difference on the reported IO values, then the table most likely isn't used.